# div has margin, but not in the inspector

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with two `<div>`s in it, but the first `<div>` called facePlus has a margin when you hover over it in the inspector, and when you scroll down to the table it says it doesn't have it:

```css
.facePlus {
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 0%;
}
.twittIn {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
.socialMedia {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="socialMedia">
  <div class="facePlus">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> Facebook<br>
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Google plus
  </div>
  <div class="twittIn">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>Twitter<br>
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>Linkedin
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **So what is your question?**

Comment: The div has a width of 50%, not a margin. Or else you're referring to the margin added to `body` by default?

Comment: how can I put them next to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I put them next to each other?

use flexbox

```css
.socialMedia {
  display: flex;
}

.socialMedia>div {
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="socialMedia">
  <div class="facePlus">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> Facebook<br>
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Google plus
  </div>
  <div class="twittIn">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>Twitter<br>
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>Linkedin
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches for you...

You can use the `display` property to place your divs side by side...

```css
.facePlus {
  width: 48%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.twittIn {
  width: 48%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="socialMedia">
  <div class="facePlus">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> Facebook<br>
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Google plus
  </div>
  <div class="twittIn">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>Twitter<br>
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>Linkedin
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use `flexbox` which you can read more about [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.socialMedia {
  display: flex;
}

.facePlus,
.twittIn {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="socialMedia">
  <div class="facePlus">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> Facebook<br>
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Google plus
  </div>
  <div class="twittIn">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>Twitter<br>
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>Linkedin
  </div>
</div>
```